# Sizing generator based upon the NEC calculation

Tags: electrical, nec, generator

What size generator would you guys recommend for a 73amp load calculation? I read that a generator should run at 80% of max amperage. Generac has a 24kW (87amp on natural gas) and a 26kW (93 amp on natural gas). 80% of these are 69amp and 74amp respectively.

1. Should I step up to a 26kw?
2. Do I need to account for a microwave? it is a high draw device
3. How do I calculate for a camera system? I have about 15 cameras running PoE.

Load managing the oven and dryer. Missed the 4 ton A/C unit, had to add that in. It's on a 40a breaker.

Here is my NEC sheet:
[image]

Comment: Is that two separate A/Cs?  Can you load-manage one of them?  EG only cool bedrooms?  For PoE just use the max draw of the switch for everything it powers.  Or if it's under 1kW just wave it into general lighting.  (If it's a residential PoE switch, 8 or 16 ports, it's probably powered by a wall wart much much less than a kW).

Comment: Curious that Generac has 22, 24, and 26kW units.  Didn't know that.  I wonder if they really produce so many different models, or if they are in fact software controlled, like Tesla features, simply to allow them to offer more price points?

Comment: What is "load managing" exactly?

Answer (score 1):

The big item is your AC. 40A breaker doesn't mean much. Need to find out how much power it actually uses.

- Should I step up to a 26kw?

No idea. A lot depends on how much you truly manage the usage (e.g., oven, dryer).

- Do I need to account for a microwave? it is a high draw device

If it is a countertop microwave then it is one of those "small appliance circuits". If it is built-in then it is really like another oven.

- How do I calculate for a camera system? I have about 15 cameras running PoE.

That's part of your "general lighting", which should be "general load and lighting". It is a constant draw, but likely not very much. A quick search shows PoE up to 30W per port which would be ~ 500W total. But very likely it is a lot less than that. Check the power supply ratings on the PoE switch. But I wouldn't worry about it much.

Keep in mind that with an automatic transfer generator, *most* of your loads will switch on automatically, so you may not have the manual load management that you expect. That being said, most ovens and dryers I've used will default to *off* after a power failure, so you will probably be OK.

Comment: Does "load managing" have a standard meaning?  Does it mean "Just don't turn those on", or does it mean put them on a load-shedding transfer switch, or put them on an subpanel that isn't backed up?  I assumed OP meant those things will not be powered, without relying on luck.

Comment: It can mean any variety of manual or automatic. My take on OP's situation is: Whole house generator, potentially powering everything, just not at the same time. Therefore, manual load management to, for example, not bake in the oven while running the dryer and vice versa. As long as (a) everyone in the house understands the constraints and (b) oven and dryer are *off* by default when the generator switches on, that will work fine. The problem would be if the system was an instant (no blink) switchover - e.g., battery backup. With a generator there is downtime between failure and backup.

Comment: I believe if there are batteries the calcs are totally different.  No?  Generator is charging batteries, not powering devices, and you don't need adequate instantaneous power, you need adequate average energy delivery to the batteries.

Comment: @jay613 All true. But at the same time, if there is instant switchover then the batteries have to be able to provide the peak demand - i.e., if it is a hot summer evening with AC + oven cooking dinner + microwave zapping more dinner + dryer running. Where with a regular generator the dryer and oven and microwave would not automatically come on when the generator starts up.

Answer (score 0):

If you only use actual loads then you need to increase the size 125%.
if you use the calculations that have the  80% rule load factors for heating and lighting you don’t need to go larger.
To provide an example the service to a home where the service supplies the entire load 100 thru 400 amps can have an ampacity of 83% so if your load calcs say 100 amps and you install a 100a panel it could be fed with #4 copper(85a) NEC 310.15.7.2. I would not cut things that close if you want your generator to last make sure it is sized 125% of the actual load or larger, don’t go crazy on sizing because cost to run gets higher with larger sizes.